# Lebesgue measure of a subset of the unit circle

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm having trouble getting started on this question:

Let $S^1$ be the unit circle. Let $m = d \theta$ be the Lebesgue measure on $S^1$. Let $M \subset S^1$ be a measurable set such that $m(M) \geq 3 \pi / 2.$ Let

$$ X = \{ \theta \in S^1: m(M \cap (\theta - 0.1, \theta + 0.1)) \leq 0.1\}. $$

Prove that $m(X) \leq \pi.$

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the Lebesgue measure on $S^1$ - arc lenght?

Comment: Pretty much. But you formally define it as a push forward of the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ under the function $e^{i\theta}.$ This will agree with arclength for any arc on the circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convolution is a powerful tool. Let $A = \{ e^{i\theta} : \lvert \theta\rvert < 0.1\}$, and $f = \chi_A \ast \chi_M$. Then you have $X = f^{-1}([0,0.1])$, and

\begin{align}
\int_{S^1} f(\theta)\,d\theta &= \int_{S^1} \int_{S^1}\chi_A(\theta-\varphi)\chi_M(\varphi)\,d\varphi\,d\theta\\
&= \int_{S^1}\int_{S^1} \chi_A(\theta-\varphi)\chi_M(\varphi)\,d\theta\,d\varphi\\
&= \int_{S^1} m(A)\chi_M(\varphi)\,d\varphi\\
&= m(A)\cdot m(M)\\
&= 0.2 m(M)\\
&\geqslant 0.2\cdot\frac{3\pi}{2}.
\end{align}

On the other hand,

\begin{align}
\int_{S^1} f(\theta)\,d\theta &= \int_X f(\theta)\,d\theta + \int_{S^1\setminus X} f(\theta)\,d\theta\\
&\leqslant 0.1\cdot m(X) + 0.2\cdot m(S^1\setminus X)\\
&= 0.2\cdot 2\pi - 0.1\cdot m(X),
\end{align}

so, combining with the above

$$0.2\cdot\frac{3\pi}{2} \leqslant 0.2\cdot 2\pi - 0.1\cdot m(X) \iff m(X) \leqslant 2\bigl(2\pi - \tfrac{3\pi}{2}\bigr) = \pi.$$